# JSF rendering the html code correctly?

Tags: html, css, jsf, editor

I'm working with jsf, primefaces 3.2, i'm using the component editor to write html code and put it to the database, the problem is when i want to display the html code, it's impacted by the css rules already defined, how cas i display my html code without being impacted by my css logic? Or how can i reset all css rules on the div i want render my html into?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable CSS by following any of the procedure in this [document](http://yaccessibilityblog.com/library/temporarily-disable-css.html).

If you do not want to inherit CSS properties for a particular element do the following.

In IE9 open Developer Tools by pressing F12. Then select the DIV element, click style tab on the right panel and uncheck all inherited properties. Same in Google Chrome. In Firefox, click on the property to disable it.

You can also stop that you include in your document head by removing them.

FYI: This is only for temporary viewing, if an element in the final page does not have to inherit any property you have to manually override that property.